"Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error when joining communities, what can I do?
What can I do when I repeatedly over a long time get the
"Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error when trying to join a community?
(I tried either Law and law.meta and both gave the same error. I have tried weeks apart and using different browsers.)
Full error:

Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified. Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://law.meta.stackexchange.com.

Of course leaving information at their feedback site is not possible since I am not allowed to join there either. Also it has been more than a week since I first tried so the error does not seem to be among the ones they "try to fix".

Maybe your IP address has been blocked due to a spammer living somewhere in your vicinity? I have heard that that is a thing that can happen.

Have you tried reaching out to support directly over the Contact Us form?

@zcoop98 done now.

@Quack, Also tried from different IP's by the way.

Looks like that you are one of the "victims" of a recent issue where a merge went wrong, and several users were affected. (I know for sure about one, with very similar symptoms, hence it's not just a wild guess.)
This caused the network profile to change, i.e. become network profile of a different person, and naturally this cause tons of problems.
This can be verified by going to your network profile, which, well, isn't yours.
Only SE staff can solve it, if you sent them a contact form all we can do now is wait. Good luck!

Not sure I fully understand what you describe. The link you gave is a hardcoded profile right? How did you find it? If I click in my profile name for example under my question it doesn't link there but to my profile instead. I tried Incognito browsing and I still don't find the link you provided?
